# Turned off display at boot stays off when turned on

Tags: boot, display, encryption, 19.10

I have connected my monitor to a power strip that I can switch on and off. If I notice after pressing the start button on the PC, that I have not yet switched the monitor on, it is too late.
Somehow the monitor is not detected then. I don't know if this is related to my lvm encryption as it asks for a password before it boots to the login screen. The only solution is to turn the PC off and on again. This time with a monitor that is switched on.

I am on Ubuntu 19.10, the monitor is connected via DisplayPort. The graphics card has several outputs and I use the latest shipped Nvidia driver.

Comment: What model of monitor are you using? Try another type of connection to the PC (HDMI or DVI) and see if that works better.